# Header file and extern keyword

Tags: c, header-files, extern

I am having a lot of issue using extern variable and header files. I have read through sections of books and searched the web for hours but I haven't been able to figure out. Any help in understanding this problem will be greatly appreciated. The following is the code and the error when I try to compile

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <string.h>
    #include "sample.h"

    int main()
      {
          int i;
          int gI = 0;
          double recv;

          i = 10;
          gI = i;

          recv = AnotherFunc();

          return 0;
      }
```

And the sample.h is the following

```
      #ifndef SAMPLE
      #define SAMPLE

      extern int gI;
      extern double AnotherFunc(); 

      #endif
```

And the other is function is

```
       #include <math.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
       #include <string.h>
       #include "sample.h"

       double AnotherFunc()
        {
           double someVar;
           int test;

           test = gI;

           someVar = 10.0;  
           return someVar;
         }
```

When I compile the following way, I get the following errors which I don't understand why I am getting those errors. sample.h has the variable declaration and it should be visible in the AnotherFunc.

```
          gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c Main.c AnotherFunc.c
          gcc Main.o AnotherFunc.o -o test
          AnotherFunc.o: In function `AnotherFunc':
          AnotherFunc.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `gI'
          collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I only added the int gI = 0; because I wanted to define it. If I modify the code in the following way I get error in main also. Please see below.

```
           #include <stdio.h>
           #include <stdlib.h>
           #include <string.h>
           #include "sample.h"

           int main(int argc, char *argv[])
            {
              int i;
              double recv;

               i = 10;
              gI = i;

              recv = AnotherFunc();

              return 0;
            }

             gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ansi -pedantic -c Main.c AnotherFunc.c
             gcc Main.o AnotherFunc.o -o test
             Main.o: In function `main':
             Main.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `gI'
             AnotherFunc.o: In function `AnotherFunc':
             AnotherFunc.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `gI'
             collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You have defined `gI` as local to `main()` - you need to declare it outside of `main()`, at global level.

Answer (score 3):

Move `int gI = 0` outside `main()` so that it is globally available:

```
int gI = 0; 
int main()
  {
      int i;

  ....
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to *declare* your variables before using them, and *define* them exactly once.

This is a declaration:

```
extern int gI;
```

Basically this just says that there is an int named `gI` that will be defined elsewhere.

This is a definition:

```
int gI;
```

This actually creates an int named `gI`.  (Technically it is a declaration as well as a definition.)

At the moment you have an `int gI` line inside of your `main` function, but this is just a shadowing definition.  It is a local variable whose name happens to be the same as the declared global `gI`, but it is not the global `gI`.  So you have a problem where you declared a variable (the global `gI`) and defined it zero times.

If you were to put `int gI` in your `sample.h` file, it would then be included in both of your `.c` files.  This would also be a problem because the rule is to define variables exactly once, and you will have defined it twice (once in each file).

The solution is to place the `extern` declaration in the `.h` file, and the definition in one of your `.c` files.

Answer (score 1):

An external variable must be defined, exactly once, outside of any function; this sets aside storage for it. The variable must also be declared in each function that wants to access it;

check this link. well explained [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)

Comment: I understand and that's why I included the sample.h in AnotherFunc. But I get the error saying undefined reference

Comment: extern keyword declares a variable, but doesn't define it, you should define the variable in 1 .c file and use the extern in the header.

Answer (score 0):

You defined gI inside the scope of the main() function, which makes it visible only from there. I suspect what you really wanted is a global gI variable (hence the extern int gI declaration).

If you want to have AnotherFunc() see it, move int gI = 0 outside, for instance in the same file than the definition of AnotherFunc().

Comment: Wouldn't including sample.h serve the purpose of declaring a variable outside the scope of main. Please look at the following code and error when I compile

Answer (score 0):

`gI` must be declared above `main`:

```
int gI = 0;

int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```

By doing this `gI` has file scope and external linkage.

Perhaps a better place to declare `gI` would be in `sample.c`, if there is such a file.